# Best way to transfer files from Xyboard to Ubuntu

Tags: android, motorola

Good day, I am trying to copy files back and forth to my Xyboard from my Ubuntu machine. From my understanding, Motorola only allows this to happen via the USB cable if Motocast is running on the computer which is currently only available for Windows and Mac. I had to create a file sharing service and then download an FTP client app to my Xyboard to accomplish the goal, but I was looking for a quicker way view the usb cable. Does anyone know how? I would also like to avoid 1) a virtual windows box 2) WINE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not very neat, but you can install andsmb on your android device, and set up your linux pc as a file server with Samba. Create a share on your linux pc, then point/configure andsmb to access that share. You can then point/click/transfer files from one machine to another.

Answer (score 1):

On my `Droid Razr`, I just use `ES File Explorer`.  It lets me browse and copy any shared Samba network files, or folders, just like any other computer.  The Droid Razr is a Linux machine, and it works just like any other Linux machine.  You just need to set permissions on your shared folders to write or whatever.  On my home network, I have a public movie/music folder that anyone can read, but nobody can write to.  I also have permissions set for individual user home folders, and private group folders.

`ES File Browser` also lets you browse all the way to root on the Android device.  In case you are curious, the flash cards are mounted under `/mnt/sdcard` for the internal card, and `/mnt/sdcard-ext` for the external removable card.  People seem to be a little confused by the Android file system, but it's Linux, with the Android windows environment running.  Android phones are Linux systems WITHOUT X-windows compiled and installed on them.

You can compile and install X-Windows on your Droid device.  Here's an Android phone running Ubuntu.  [Ubuntu on Android Phone](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JVSNIJs0lWw)

Answer (score 0):

I installed mtpfs from synaptic. I restarted my computer and my tablet but I don't think you have to. Worked perfect.

EDIT: only works for camera mode. not MTP. :-(